# Vusual studio code @flow create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype, create-react-app

I have installed [Flow-IDE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode) into my vscode for better experience.
And, obviously, flow-bin globally.
Then, [per flow instructions](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/children/) I'm trying to set prop types for my `create-react-app`
But I got 2 issues:
1 for children

```
Cannot get `React.Node` because property `Node` is missing in object type
```

also `Flow-IDE doesn't see paths: Cannot resolve module app/components/...etc...`

How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.flowconfig to the rescue:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/build/.*

[include]

[libs]
flow-typed

[lints]

[options]
all=true
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules

esproposal.decorators=ignore
esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable

suppress_type=$FlowIssue
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe

[strict]
```